# Integrate by parts: $\int \ln (2x + 1) \, dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms

$$\eqalign{
  & \int \ln (2x + 1) \, dx  \cr 
  & u = \ln (2x + 1)  \cr 
  & v = x  \cr 
  & {du \over dx} = {2 \over 2x + 1}  \cr 
  & {dv \over dx} = 1  \cr 
  & \int \ln (2x + 1) \, dx = x\ln (2x + 1) - \int {2x \over 2x + 1} \cr 
  &  = x\ln (2x + 1) - \int 1 - {1 \over {2x + 1}}   \cr 
  &  = x\ln (2x + 1) - (x - {1 \over 2}\ln |2x + 1|)  \cr 
  &  = x\ln (2x + 1) + \ln |(2x + 1)^{1 \over 2}| - x + C  \cr 
  &  = x\ln (2x + 1)^{3 \over 2} - x + C \cr} $$

---

The answer $ = {1 \over 2}(2x + 1)\ln (2x + 1) - x + C$

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your last equality.  You can't combine the log terms as you have done because only one of them has a factor of $x$.  Instead, you should bring the $\frac{1}{2}$ down, and then factor out $\ln(2x+1)$.

Comment: You're also missing two $\mathrm dx$, and parentheses around $\displaystyle1-\frac1{2x+1}$.

Comment: And you can use substitution $t = 2x+1$ and then to apply integration by parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from your second to last line (your integration was fine, minus a few $dx$'s in you integrals):

$$ = x\ln (2x + 1) + \ln |{(2x + 1)^{{1 \over 2}}}| - x + C  \tag{1}$$

Good, up to this point... $\uparrow$.

So the error was in your last equality at the very end:

You made an error by ignoring the fact that the first term with $\ln(2x+1)$ as a factor **also** has $x$ as a factor, so we cannot multiply the arguments of $\ln$ to get $\ln(2x+1)^{3/2}$. What you could have done was *first* express $x\ln(2x+1) = \ln(2x+1)^x$ and **then** proceed as you did in your answer, but your result will then agree with your text's solution.

Alternatively, we can factor out like terms.

$$ = x\ln(2x + 1) + \frac 12 \ln(2x + 1) - x + C \tag{1}$$
$$= \color{blue}{\bf \frac 12 }{\cdot \bf 2x} \color{blue}{\bf \ln(2x+1)} + \color{blue}{\bf \frac 12 \ln(2x+1)}\cdot {\bf 1} - x + C$$

Factoring out $\color{blue}{\bf \frac 12 \ln(2x + 1)}$ gives us

$$= \left(\dfrac 12\ln(2x + 1)\right)\cdot \left(2x +1\right) - x + C $$ $$= \frac 12(2x + 1)\ln(2x+1) - x + C$$

Comment: Why can't I do:

$$\eqalign{
  &  = \ln {(2x + 1)^x} + \ln |{(2x + 1)^{{1 \over 2}}}| - x + C  \cr 
  &  = \ln {(2x + 1)^{x + {1 \over 2}}} - x + C \cr} $$

Comment: You're welcome, Assad: note, your procedure would have worked, had you done the arithmetic a little better: see the other answer, e.g. Note also that when it comes to integrals, especially when working with logarithms, many "different *appearing* solutions can be derived, depending on one's manipulations, etc.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice to get ack'ed by OP! +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is a cute variant. Let $u=\ln(2x+1)$ and let $dv=dx$. Then $du=\frac{2}{2x+1}$ and (this is the cute part) **we can take** $v=x+\frac{1}{2}$. It follows that
$$\int \ln(2x+1)\,dx=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(2x+1)-\int \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{2}{2x+1}\,dx.$$
But the remaining integrand is just $1$! It follows that our integral is
$$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(2x+1) -x+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are more tidy ways to do this but as an alternative...

Why not do $\int \ln(2x + 1)dx$ using:

$v^\prime = 1 \Rightarrow v = x$ and $u = \ln(2x+1)\Rightarrow u^\prime=\frac{2}{2x+1}$

Therefore,

$$\int \ln(2x + 1)dx = x\ln(2x+1) - \int \frac{2x}{2x+1}dx$$

Then make the substitution $u=2x + 1$ to yield,

$$\int \ln(2x + 1)dx = x\ln(2x+1) - \int \frac{1}{2}\frac{u-1}{u}du$$

Thus,

$$\int \ln(2x + 1)dx = x\ln(2x+1) - \frac{1}{2}u - ln(u) + c$$

Then,

$$\int \ln(2x + 1)dx = x\ln(2x+1) - \frac{1}{2}(2x-1) - \ln(2x-1) + c$$

$$= \ln(2x-1)(x-1) - \frac{1}{2}(2x-1) + c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ = x\ln (2x + 1) + \ln |{(2x + 1)^{{1 \over 2}}}| - x + C  $$

$$ = \ln(2x + 1)^x +  \ln(2x + 1)^\dfrac 12 - x + C $$

$$= \ln({(2x + 1)^x \cdot(2x + 1)^\dfrac 12}) - x + C $$
$$= \ln{(2x + 1)^\dfrac{2x+1}{2} } - x + C $$
$$= \dfrac {1}{2}\cdot (2x+1) \ln{(2x + 1)} - x + C $$

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put $u = 2x + 1$ so that $du = 2 \,dx$? Then we'd have $$\int \log (2x + 1) \, dx = \frac {1} {2} \int \log u \, du = \frac {1} {2} (u \log u - u) = \frac {1} {2} (2x + 1) \log (2x + 1) - x - \frac {1} {2} + C.$$